# RXjs issues when deployed on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, angular

I have a nodeJS / Angular2 based site which works fine on my local Windows 10 machine. However, when I try to deploy to Heroku and access the site, the front end console (Chrome) throws the following error and the site doesn't load.

> zone.js:101 GET https://ns-docs.herokuapp.com/node_modules/rxjs/RX.js 404 (Not Found)

[image]

my [`systemjs.config.js`](https://github.com/georgeedwards/docs/blob/master/ng2/config/systemjs.config.js) contains this:

```
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        '/app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   '/node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       '/node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

and my [`index.html`](https://github.com/georgeedwards/docs/blob/master/ng2/views/index.html) contains:

```
...
    <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="/config/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

## Update:

So if I run the project locally, `http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/RX.js` shows the js source.
However, if I push the project to Heroku, with [this](https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/f1f1e2ecfbf0fe9688a665075db14eb1) build log, that version returns a 404 on `/node_modules/rxjs/RX.js`

Comment: Does `Rx.js` exist on your deploy `node_modules/rxjs/RX.js` location? otherwise change location path accordingly in your `systemjs.config.js` file.

Comment: @Sanket No, if I run the project locally, `http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/RX.js` shows the js source, however, the exact same project returns a 404 on Heroku?

Comment: what do you mean by exact same project... are you deploying entire node_modules folder on Heroku and still getting this error?

Comment: @Sanket So I have a repo with a `package.json` which installs a node_modules dir. If I run `git push heroku master` and watch [this](https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/8769e7ad8c238b527b582ceb94324820) output, then some(?) of the dependencies get installed and the result throws this issue. The same repo works locally

Comment: check line 84 and 111 in logs, it says - `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11`

Comment: Since you are using angular RC5, just try changing to rxjs from `5.0.0-beta.11` to `5.0.0-beta.6` this might work for you.

Comment: @Sanket I'm afraid it's the same with rxjs -beta.6

Answer (score 0):

In your packages you haven't specified the main script for rxjs.
This is what I do in in my AngularRC.6:

'rxjs': {main: 'Rx'}

Comment: I'm afraid with that with `'rxjs': { main: 'Rx', defaultExtension: 'js' },` I still get the same error...